# how does perl uniquely identify package variables?

Tags: perl, variables

Hi I'm new to Perl programming and i have just encountered these type of variables in Perl:
**package and lexical**

and so far i learned that this is a package variable:

```
$Santa::Helper::Reindeer::Rudolph::nose
```

So my question is, how does Perl know if I'm referring to `$nose, or @nose or %nose` inside that package?

and is this also valid if i declare another variable (a lexical one) with the name

`$nose or @nose or %nose` using **my**:

example: `my $nose;`

Comment: cause inside that package there might be 3 different type of variables with the same name - nose

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When in scope of `package Santa::Helper::Reindeer::Rudolph;`,

`$nose` is short for `$Santa::Helper::Reindeer::Rudolph::nose`

and

`@nose` is short for `@Santa::Helper::Reindeer::Rudolph::nose`.

That is, unless you've created a lexical variable (using `my $nose;` or `our $nose;`) that's in scope. If so, whichever variable you declare last is the one used.

```
package Santa::Helper::Reindeer::Rudolph;
$Santa::Helper::Reindeer::Rudolph::nose = 123;
print "$nose\n";      # 123

my $nose = 456;       # Creates new lexical var
print "$Santa::Helper::Reindeer::Rudolph::nose\n";  # 123
print "$nose\n";      # 456

{
   my $nose = 789;    # Creates new lexical var
   print "$nose\n";   # 789
}
print "$nose\n";      # 456

our $nose;            # Creates lexical var aliased to $S::H::R::R::nose
print "$nose\n";      # 123
```

Comment: so `$Santa::Helper::Reindeer::Rudolph::nose = 123;` and `our $nose` is just the same?

Comment: No, one's an assignment, and the other is a variable declaration. The variable in the latter is aliased to the variable in the former, though.

Comment: if i asign something to `our $nose` will the packages `$nose` change too? and is `our` only used to re declare (alias) a package?

Comment: It will change `$Santa::Helper::Reindeer::Rudolph::nose`, not necessarily the current package's `$nose`. `package` is the only way to declare packages. `use vars` is the only way to declare package variables.

Comment: Very descriptive examples.

Answer (score 5):

```
$Santa::Helper::Reindeer::Rudolph::nose
```

is `$nose`

```
@Santa::Helper::Reindeer::Rudolph::nose
```

is `@nose`

If the package uses a lexically scoped variable by declaring `our $nose`, and you declare `my $nose` in your code which uses that package you will clobber it. If you `use strict` and `use warnings` (which you always should) then it will give you a warning when this happens like: `"my" variable $nose masks earlier declaration in same scope`. If the package uses a private variable by declaring `my $nose`, then you can also declare `my $nose` in your code, and the package's `$nose` will be unaffected.

Comment: so what if i declare another variable named `nose` using `my`?

Comment: can i use the packaged declaration of `my $nose` and also my code of `my $nose` too?

Comment: yes, just refer to the package's `$nose` by `$Santa::Helper::Reindeer::Rudolph::nose` and yours by `$nose`